# function .click não funciona em mobile

Tags: jquery

fiz um formulário de cadastro usando jquery, e funciona 100% no desktop mais em navegadores mobile não funciona o '.click(function(){' .... abaixo segue um trecho do meu arquivo .js, se alguém puder dar uma força eu fico muito grato.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#formulario").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        return false;
    } else {


        $(function(){
var atual_fs, next_fs, prev_fs;
var formulario = $('form[name=formulario]');

function next(elem){
    atual_fs = $(elem).parent();
    next_fs = $(elem).parent().next();


    $('#progress li').eq($('fieldset').index(next_fs)).addClass('ativo');
    atual_fs.hide(800);
    next_fs.show(800);
}


$('.prev').click(function(){
    atual_fs = $(this).parent();
    prev_fs = $(this).parent().prev();


    $('#progress li').eq($('fieldset').index(atual_fs)).removeClass('ativo');
    atual_fs.hide(800);
    prev_fs.show(800);
});

$('input[name=next1]').click(function(){
    var array = formulario.serializeArray();
        if(array[0].value == '' || array[1].value == '' || array[2].value == '' || array[3].value == '' || array[4].value == '' || array[5].value == '' || array[6].value == '' || array[7].value == '' || array[8].value == '' || array[9].value == '' || array[10].value == '' || array[11].value == '' || array[12].value == '' || array[13].value == '' || array[14].value == '' || array[15].value == '' || array[16].value == '' || array[17].value == '' || array[18].value == '' || array[19].value == ''){

        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Preencha todos os dados da primeira etapa, para poder ir para a segunda etapa!</p></div>');          
    }else{

        nome = array[0].value;

if(nome.length < 9) {
        $('#nome').css('background', '#FF6266');
        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>DIGITE SEU NOME COMPLETO</p></div>');
```

}else {

```
    $('#nome').css('background', '#A3F587');
telefone = array[13].value;

if(telefone.length < 9) {
        $('#telefone').css('background', '#FF6266');
        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>DIGITE UM TELEFONE VÁLIDO</p></div>');

}else {
    $('#telefone').css('background', '#A3F587');

    celular = array[14].value;

if(celular.length < 9) {
        $('#telefone').css('background', '#A3F587');
        $('#celular').css('background', '#FF6266');
        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>DIGITE UM CELULAR VÁLIDO</p></div>');
}else {

        $('#celular').css('background', '#A3F587');
            strCPF = array[15].value;

            strCPF = strCPF.replace(/[^\d]+/g,''); 
            var Soma; 
            var Resto; 
            var cboll = true; 
            Soma = 0; 

            if (strCPF.length != 11 || 
                strCPF == "00000000000" || 
                strCPF == "11111111111" || 
                strCPF == "22222222222" || 
                strCPF == "33333333333" || 
                strCPF == "44444444444" || 
                strCPF == "55555555555" || 
                strCPF == "66666666666" || 
                strCPF == "77777777777" || 
                strCPF == "88888888888" || 
                strCPF == "99999999999") 
                cboll = false; 


                for (i=1; i<=9; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i-1, i)) * (11 - i); 
                Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11; 

                if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11)) Resto = 0; 
                if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(9, 10)) ) cboll = false; 

                Soma = 0; 
                for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) Soma = Soma + parseInt(strCPF.substring(i-1, i)) * (12 - i); 
                Resto = (Soma * 10) % 11; 

                if ((Resto == 10) || (Resto == 11)) Resto = 0; 
                if (Resto != parseInt(strCPF.substring(10, 11) ) ) cboll = false; 

                if(!cboll){ 
                    $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>CPF INVÁLIDO</p></div>');
                    $('#cpf').css('background', '#FF6266');

                }else {

                    $('#cpf').css('background', '#A3F587');
rg = array[16].value;

if (rg.length < 6 ||
```

rg == "" ||
rg == "00000" ||
rg == "000000" ||
rg == "0000000" ||
rg == "00000000" ||
rg == "000000000" ||
rg == "0000000000" ||
rg == "00000000000" ||
rg == "000000000000" ||
rg == "0000000000000" ||
rg == "00000000000000" ||
rg == "000000000000000" ||
rg == "0000000000000000" ||
rg == "000000000000000000" ||
rg == "0000000000000000000" ||
rg == "00000000000000000000" ||
rg == "000000000000000000000" ||
rg == "0000000000000000000000" ||
rg == "00000000000000000000000" ||
rg == "111111" ||
rg == "1111111" ||
rg == "11111111" ||
rg == "111111111" ||
rg == "1111111111" ||
rg == "111111111111" ||
rg == "1111111111111" ||
rg == "11111111111111" ||
rg == "111111111111111" ||
rg == "1111111111111111" ||
rg == "11111111111111111" ||
rg == "111111111111111111" ||
rg == "1111111111111111111" ||
rg == "11111111111111111111" ||
rg == "111111111111111111111" ||
rg == "1111111111111111111111" ||
rg == "11111111111111111111111" ||
rg == "111111111111111111111111" ||
rg == "1111111111111111111111111" ||
rg == "11111111111111111111111111" ||
rg == "222222" ||
rg == "2222222" ||
rg == "22222222" ||
rg == "222222222" ||
rg == "2222222222" ||
rg == "222222222222" ||
rg == "2222222222222" ||
rg == "22222222222222" ||
rg == "222222222222222" ||
rg == "2222222222222222" ||
rg == "22222222222222222" ||
rg == "222222222222222222" ||
rg == "2222222222222222222" ||
rg == "22222222222222222222" ||
rg == "222222222222222222222" ||
rg == "2222222222222222222222" ||
rg == "22222222222222222222222" ||
rg == "222222222222222222222222" ||
rg == "2222222222222222222222222" ||
rg == "22222222222222222222222222" ||
rg == "333333" ||
rg == "3333333" ||
rg == "33333333" ||
rg == "333333333" ||
rg == "3333333333" ||
rg == "333333333333" ||
rg == "3333333333333" ||
rg == "33333333333333" ||
rg == "333333333333333" ||
rg == "3333333333333333" ||
rg == "33333333333333333" ||
rg == "333333333333333333" ||
rg == "3333333333333333333" ||
rg == "33333333333333333333" ||
rg == "333333333333333333333" ||
rg == "3333333333333333333333" ||
rg == "33333333333333333333333" ||
rg == "333333333333333333333333" ||
rg == "3333333333333333333333333" ||
rg == "33333333333333333333333333" || 
rg == "444444" ||
rg == "4444444" ||
rg == "44444444" ||
rg == "444444444" ||
rg == "4444444444" ||
rg == "444444444444" ||
rg == "4444444444444" ||
rg == "44444444444444" ||
rg == "444444444444444" ||
rg == "4444444444444444" ||
rg == "44444444444444444" ||
rg == "444444444444444444" ||
rg == "4444444444444444444" ||
rg == "44444444444444444444" ||
rg == "444444444444444444444" ||
rg == "4444444444444444444444" ||
rg == "44444444444444444444444" ||
rg == "444444444444444444444444" ||
rg == "4444444444444444444444444" ||
rg == "44444444444444444444444444" ||
rg == "555555" ||
rg == "5555555" ||
rg == "55555555" ||
rg == "555555555" ||
rg == "5555555555" ||
rg == "555555555555" ||
rg == "5555555555555" ||
rg == "55555555555555" ||
rg == "555555555555555" ||
rg == "5555555555555555" ||
rg == "55555555555555555" ||
rg == "555555555555555555" ||
rg == "5555555555555555555" ||
rg == "55555555555555555555" ||
rg == "555555555555555555555" ||
rg == "5555555555555555555555" ||
rg == "55555555555555555555555" ||
rg == "555555555555555555555555" ||
rg == "5555555555555555555555555" ||
rg == "55555555555555555555555555" ||
rg == "666666" ||
rg == "6666666" ||
rg == "66666666" ||
rg == "666666666" ||
rg == "6666666666" ||
rg == "666666666666" ||
rg == "6666666666666" ||
rg == "66666666666666" ||
rg == "666666666666666" ||
rg == "6666666666666666" ||
rg == "66666666666666666" ||
rg == "666666666666666666" ||
rg == "6666666666666666666" ||
rg == "66666666666666666666" ||
rg == "666666666666666666666" ||
rg == "6666666666666666666666" ||
rg == "66666666666666666666666" ||
rg == "666666666666666666666666" ||
rg == "6666666666666666666666666" ||
rg == "66666666666666666666666666" ||
rg == "777777" ||
rg == "7777777" ||
rg == "77777777" ||
rg == "777777777" ||
rg == "7777777777" ||
rg == "777777777777" ||
rg == "7777777777777" ||
rg == "77777777777777" ||
rg == "777777777777777" ||
rg == "7777777777777777" ||
rg == "77777777777777777" ||
rg == "777777777777777777" ||
rg == "7777777777777777777" ||
rg == "77777777777777777777" ||
rg == "777777777777777777777" ||
rg == "7777777777777777777777" ||
rg == "77777777777777777777777" ||
rg == "777777777777777777777777" ||

rg == "7777777777777777777777777" ||
rg == "77777777777777777777777777" ||
rg == "888888" ||
rg == "8888888" ||
rg == "88888888" ||
rg == "888888888" ||
rg == "8888888888" ||
rg == "888888888888" ||
rg == "8888888888888" ||
rg == "88888888888888" ||
rg == "888888888888888" ||
rg == "8888888888888888" ||
rg == "88888888888888888" ||
rg == "888888888888888888" ||
rg == "8888888888888888888" ||
rg == "88888888888888888888" ||
rg == "888888888888888888888" ||
rg == "8888888888888888888888" ||
rg == "88888888888888888888888" ||
rg == "888888888888888888888888" ||
rg == "8888888888888888888888888" ||
rg == "88888888888888888888888888" ||
rg == "999999" ||
rg == "9999999" ||
rg == "99999999" ||
rg == "999999999" ||
rg == "9999999999" ||
rg == "999999999999" ||
rg == "9999999999999" ||
rg == "99999999999999" ||
rg == "999999999999999" ||
rg == "9999999999999999" ||
rg == "99999999999999999" ||
rg == "999999999999999999" ||
rg == "9999999999999999999" ||
rg == "99999999999999999999" ||
rg == "999999999999999999999" ||
rg == "9999999999999999999999" ||
rg == "99999999999999999999999" ||
rg == "999999999999999999999999" ||
rg == "9999999999999999999999999" ||
rg == "99999999999999999999999999") {

$('.resp').html('

RG INVÁLIDO

');
$('#rg').css('background', '#FF6266');

}else {

```
$('#rg').css('background', '#A3F587');
        $('.resp').html('');
        next($(this));
```

}
                    }
        }
    }

```
}
```

}

```
});

$('input[name=next2]').click(function(){
    var array = formulario.serializeArray();
    if(array[20].value == '' || array[21].value == '' || array[22].value == '' || array[23].value == '' || array[24].value == ''){

        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Informe-nos seus dados prossionais, para podermos continuar!</p></div>');
    }else{

        $('.resp').html('');
        next($(this));
    }
});


$('input[name=next3]').click(function(){
    var array = formulario.serializeArray();
    if(array[26].value == '' || array[27].value == '' || array[28].value == '' || array[29].value == '' || array[30].value == ''){

        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Informe-nos sua formação acadêmica, para podermos continuar!</p></div>');
    }else{

        $('.resp').html('');
        next($(this));
    }
});




$('input[name=next4]').click(function(evento){
    var array = formulario.serializeArray();
    if(array[31].value == '' || array[32].value == '' || array[33].value == '' || array[34].value == '' || array[35].value == ''){

        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Informe-nos os últimos dados, para podermos efetuar seu cadastro com exito!</p></div>');

    }else{ //else global



        if(array[32].value != array[33].value){

                $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>E-Mail não confere</p></div>');
        }else {

            var sEmail  = $("#email").val();
    // filtros
    var emailFilter=/^.+@.+\..{2,}$/;
    var illegalChars= /[\(\)\<\>\,\;\:\\\/\"\[\]]/
    // condição
    if(!(emailFilter.test(sEmail))||sEmail.match(illegalChars)){
        $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>E-MAIL INVÁLIDO</p></div>');
        $('#email').css('background', '#FF6266');

    }else {

        var senhaa = array[34].value;
        var csenhaa = array[35].value;

                if(senhaa.length < 4 || csenhaa.length < 4){

            $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Senha deve ter no minímo 4 digítos</p></div>');

            }else {

                if(array[34].value != array[35].value){

                $('.resp').html('<div class="erros"><p>Senhas não conferem</p></div>');
        }else {

            $('#formulario').submit();

        }

            }

    }

        }


    } // else global final

});
```

});

```
    }

});
```

});

Comment: Esse código não está completo. Podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar isso?

Comment: Editei e coloquei completo, ficou meio esquisito porque não sei usar direito porque sou novo na comunidade kkk.

Comment: você já tentou no pc emular pelo chrome como celular e verificar o que ocorre no console, se não, coloque alert() ao iniciar cada função e teste no celular e veja até que parte ele executa.